# Jasper bar graph

Tags: jasper-reports

Just want to ask is it possible for jasper to generate a stacked bar graph like the following? If yes, how can I do that? Many thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible without integration of JasperReport server with any other chart libraries, In current Ireport you can use only existing stack bar chart and then you can set graph property " Show labels" using this property you can see the values in bar.